# function goes to an infinite loop when converted to exe using pyinstaller and multiprocessing

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, pyinstaller

Here I have a simple program.

```
import multiprocessing
import dicc

def comb():
    name = input("What is your name: ")
    print([i for i in range(10)])


def zomb():
    dicc.work() #this func do not print anything.
if __name__=="__main__":
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=zomb)
    p1.start()

    comb()
```

As long as this program is in .py extension , it is working fine but when i convert this to .exe , my **comb()** function goes to an infinite loop. It keeps on asking input. What is wrong? How do i fix this? I tried using **multiprocessing.freeze_support()** its useless.

Comment: Are you positive that you have included a call to `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` _right after_ the `__name__ == "__main__"` guard?

Comment: windows `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` it went into an infinite loop as you described. But after adding it right after `__main__` and recompiling it worked as intended